# JOptionPane cancel button and getting input

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to get the user to input there name if it is left blank it will ask again, if they fill it out it sets a `JLabel` or hit cancel to get out.
My last if statement is wrong it does not like `nameEnt`.

```
public Player() {
    //setBackground(Color.green);
    setSize(600, 400);
    name = new JLabel();//Input hint
    JOptionPane nameOption = new JOptionPane();
    String nameEnt = nameOption.showInputDialog("First Name: ");
    if (!nameEnt.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
        name.setText(nameEnt);
    }
    if (nameEnt.length() == 0) {
        //if this condition is true JOption stays until name is entered or canceled 
    }
    if (nameEnt == nameOption.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), if the user cancels the dialog, `null` is returned.

And so the correct solution is to to not to use equals, but rather to check the return value for null and to do this first, **before** checking its length.

```
public Player() {
    //setBackground(Color.green);
    setSize(600, 400);
    name = new JLabel();//Input hint
    JOptionPane nameOption = new JOptionPane();
    String nameEnt = nameOption.showInputDialog("First Name: ");
    if (nameEnt == null) {
        // user canceled. get out of here. 
        System.exit(0);

        // or return;  
        // or throw some exception
    }
    if (!nameEnt.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
        name.setText(nameEnt);
    }
    if (nameEnt.length() == 0) {
        //if this condition is true JOption stays until name is entered or canceled 
    }
    // if (nameEnt == nameOption.CANCEL_OPTION) {
       //  System.exit(0);
    // }
}
```

But why are you creating a JOptionPane this way? Better to use the static method of creation.

```
// don't use null as the first parameter if the GUI is already showing
String nameEnt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "First Name: ");
if (nameEnt == null) {
    // user canceled. get out of here. 
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Or maybe something like this, if you're trying to loop to get input:

```
public Player() {
    setSize(600, 400);  // This is not good to do. Ask for details and I'll tell.

    name = new JLabel();// Don't forget to add this to the GUI!

    String nameEnt = "";
    while (nameEnt.trim().isEmpty()) {
        // if the GUI is already showing, pass a component from it as the first param here, not null
        nameEnt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "First Name: ");
        if (nameEnt == null) {
            // user canceled. get out of here. 
            System.exit(0);

            // or return;  
            // or throw some exception
        } else if (!nameEnt.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            name.setText(nameEnt);
        } else {
            // set it to "" so that we keep looping
            nameEnt = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If user does not enter letters or leaves it blank hoe do I get the window to come up again?

Comment: @JamesParker: you test for blank with `myString.trim().isEmpty()`. You repeat by using a while loop. But if this is for a GUI, I'd wire things up completely differently myself.

Comment: It is for a GUI, It so I can have the player enter their name for an hangman game

Comment: @JamesParker: there are multiple classes for this project? Again, I would wire things differently. The Player class should have no GUI code or user interaction code within it, such as JOptionPane or JLabel. That goes within the Game class. Player should just contain Player information, and should be more JavaBean structured with basic constructor, getters, setters, score field, etc...

Comment: so I have four classes Player, Words(dictionary), Hangman(paints the pic) and Game Engine. So what your saying is that the JOptionPane and JLabel should be in the GameEngine. Which makes sense, but I not sure what be in the player class?

Comment: @JamesParker: the *state* of the Player -- name, score (if needed), number of wrong guesses,...

Answer (score 2):

The `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION` is a static int field, and you can't compare `String` with `int` with `==`.

---

**Good practice**

In your case you want to use ok and cancel button `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` and `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` in one shot and this is not possible, i suggest to use this instead :

```
JTextField nameF = new JTextField(20);//create TextField

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();//cerate JPanel
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Name"));
myPanel.add(nameF);//add your JTextField to your panel

int result;
do {
    result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
            "Title of Panel", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);//add your panel to JOptionPane
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {//if the user press OK then
        if (nameF.getText().isEmpty()) {//check if the input is empty
            //if this condition is true JOption stays until name is entered or canceled 
        } else if (!nameF.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {//check if the input match with your regex
            //name match exactly
            //name.setText(nameF.getText());
        }
    }
} while (result != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);//If the user hit cancel then exit
```

Comment: 1. Shouldn't the OP use the static version of that field, `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION`, 2. Isn't that field an int and not a String?

Comment: Edit, double checked, and yes, CANCEL_OPTION  is a static int field. Don't use `.equals` to test it, but rather `==`.

Comment: yes this is true @HovercraftFullOfEels already edit it it still you can't compare a String with int using `==` you should to use `.equals`

Comment: Incompatible operand types String and int "if(nameEnt == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)"

Comment: Exactly. He shouldn't be comparing a String with an int in the first place. It makes no sense.

Comment: yes, thank you for your help @HovercraftFullOfEels ;)